# subdomain changes image path

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, subdomain

I have one dynamic website with back end control panel which contains ckEditor  for data entry.
 ckEditor inserts images with path like: **/userfiles/image1.jpg** and when I call page to display on user interface it shows perfect if I access it from main url but due to some reasons few section we have to move on a sub folder and when I access same page from that subdomain it fails in displaying image.
when I checked url of the image, it shows like:
**app1.mysite.com/userFiles/image1.jpg** 
But the actual path is:
**mysite.com/userFiles/image1.jpg.**

Is there any trick or technique to solve this?
I am using PHP.

Comment: Yes, in ckeditor, put in the full path to the image, not just `/theimage`. For example, `http://mysite.com/userFiles/image1.jpg`. The alternative is to use regex when outputting the text to the page that replaces `/userFiles/` with `http://mysite.com/userFiles/`

Comment: can you please guide how ti use regex?

Comment: I'd rather not, it really isn't a very good solution. htaccess would be a pretty transparent way of solving it. Detect if you are on the subdomain, and if you are, redirect all requests to `/userFiles/` to `http://mysite.com/userFiles/`. I would post it as an answer with an example, but i don't have an example to post.

Comment: please share, I am not skilled in htaccess file but trying.
RewriteRule ^http://test.mysite.com/userFiles/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/userFiles/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Neither am I, though i do know it may need a rewrite condition in addition to a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `<base>` in your `<head>`:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

To do ist with PHP is hard. Changing it beforehand to an absolute URL might be the best way, changing it afterwards means HTML scanning, finding the images, check wether the url is absolute or relative and change it, if needed.

Comment: thanks for reply, I have two folders from images coming also few are on same subdomain for interface purpose.
during search I think solution is in htaccess file. but yet no idea.