# images from main domain to subdomain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [subdomain changes image path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125464/subdomain-changes-image-path)

I have some articles in database entered by ckEditor which uses path like
/userfiles/image1.jpg

and when I access them from a sub domain it makes my url like
test.mysite.com/userfiles/image1.jpg and get error file not found.
the actual path is mysite.com/userfile/image1.com

how to solve this problem
I am using php

Comment: Is it posible to use the full path to the image?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use an absolute url in the editor, e.g.

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/userfiles/image1.jpg">
```

or, if those sites are hosted on the same physical server, you could create a virtual directory (e.g. Apache `Alias`) so that `/userfiles` on both sites point at the same physical directory on the server.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a vhost which points to the same directory as your main site!